# A simple query to check for server liveliness

Tags: sql-server

In order to the determine the 'liveliness' of a remote SQL-server, I need to periodically address the server with some query.

I am looking for a query which will generate minimal server work, and minimal communications overhead (both for the query and the reply).

The query should work on SQL-Server 2005 and 2008 at least, and should not assume existance of some database or table, and should not generate errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
select 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Andrejs Cainikovs answer of `select 1` is good. No database or table dependencies, minimal data, etc.

A couple of days ago, I ran a SQL Profiler on a SQL Server 2005 server, and one of the SQL Statements that I saw every few secons was: `SELECT N'Testing Connection...'` which has the advantage of documentation for someone observing the server. So maybe something like:

```
select 'Testing connection from server Y for application X'
```

A little more data would need to be put on the wire, but it would allow anyone profiling the server to know exactly why those selects were showing up.

Comment: Consider adding @@SERVERNAME to your SELECT.

Comment: @Rod: Why? I'm presuming that the calling routine already knows which server it is calling.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1+1
```

though you should be able to check whether the server is responding without performing a query.

Answer (score 0):

select spid from master..sysprocesses

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GetDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME as ServerName
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "smallest table you have access to"
```

Comment: That introduces table and database dependencies.